# C# - DropDown ComboBox - how can a user add value using nothing else?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I would like to solve my problem using only a DropDown ComboBox component. Although I have a list of colors, I want to allow user to enter an RGB color code.

In my imagination it would work two ways:

- **The user** opens the Dropdown section and **choses the wanted color**
- **The user enters an RGB code** (eg. 255;0;123) through the component's editable first line (then presses enter)

*(I don't need (neither want) the RGB code to be added to the list of the ComboBox.)*

I only need the results of that; **I can process the outcoming data.**

Comment: Extremely simple. Set `ComboBox.DropDownStyle` to `ComboBoxStyle.DropDown`.

Comment: i have already sat that. Still can't get the custom data of the first editable line.

Comment: What do you mean that you can't get the data? Use ComboBox.Text.

Comment: Thanks. It Works....... (i am ashamed i haven't tried it before)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the ComboBox's "KeyDown" event. In the below I'm using "exampleProcess" as a method used when you have a colour you wish to use. I'm going to add an array of your example colours as comparisons also.

```
string[] colours = new string[]{"Red","Green","Blue","Yellow","etc"};//These would be the values in your combobox dropdown list.
Color selectedcolour;
private void ComboBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)//If enter key pressed.
    {
        if (colours.Contains(ComboBox.Text))//If the colour is one of the default colours.
        {
            selectedcolour = Color.FromName(ComboBox.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            List<string> parts = ComboBox.Text.Split(';');//Split text into parts between each ";".
            foreach(string part in parts)
            {
                if (part == "")
                {
                    parts.Remove(part);
                }
            }
            int r = int.Parse(parts[0]);
            int g = int.Parse(parts[1]);
            int b = int.Parse(parts[2]);
            selectedcolour = Color.FromArgb(r,g,b);
        }
        exampleProcess(selectedcolour);
    }
}
```

You'll have to add more error checking but I think this should essentially work ^_^.